# reverse asort result

Tags: php, sorting

very simple but confused me! here is it:

```
$command[] = "30";
$command[] = "20";
$command[] = "10";
$command[] = "5";
$command[] = "1";

asort($command);

print_r($command);
```

return:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 30 [1] => 20 [2] => 10 [3] => 5 [4] => 1
>   ) )

but I want:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 5 [2] => 10 [3] => 20 [4] => 30
>   ) )

exact code I use:

```
$cmd_id = array();

foreach ($_POST as $k => $v)
{
    if($k=='cmd_id' && $v>0)
        $cmd_id[] = $v;
}
```

form is multiple checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cmd_id[]" .........
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you're putting your integers into "strings"?

Comment: I get these from $_POST. foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) etc...

Comment: Your output is somewhat different from your sample code. `print_r` suggests that `$command` contains *one* key whose value is the array containing these numbers.

Comment: actual code is:    $cmd_id = array();
   
   foreach ($_POST as $k => $v)
   {
    if($k=='cmd_id' && $v>0)
     $cmd_id[] = $v;
  
   }

Comment: `array_reverse(asort($command));`- hacks!

Comment: @binnyb: Will not work. `asort` sorts in-place and returns true or false.

Comment: @exim: `var_dump` the array before sorting it. You will find an array containing another array. Fun fact: `array() > 0 === true`.

Comment: Is `cmd_id` coming in from checkboxes or a multiple select form by any chance?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 yes these are checkboxes: name='cmd_id[]'

Comment: `asort($command); $command = array_reverse($command);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your value seems to be an array of values. I'm assuming that in your HTML, you have something like `name="cmd_id[]"` in the form. Therefore, the HTTP POST variable `cmd_id` will arrive to PHP in array form.

```
$cmd_id = array();

foreach ($_POST['cmd_id'] as $value) {
    if($value > 0) {
        $cmd_id[] = $value;
    }
}

sort($cmd_id, SORT_NATURAL);

print_r($cmd_id);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `arsort` - just reverse version of `asort`

Answer (score 2):

Original anwer: use [arsort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php).

--

Update: asort is for maintaining the indexes, what you want is the normal [sort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)(). Also, see [Sorting Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) in the php manual

--

Update 2:
The issue is with how you populate your array. Instead do this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['cmd_id'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['cmd_id') {
        $cmd_id[] = intval($v); # Preferably force ints if you expect ints
    }
} else { /* Handle use input failure accordingly */ }
```

Comment: Your code output indicates you are not sorting the array you think, but rather an array that holds the array you actually want to be sorted. array(array("30", "20", ...))